# Deleting words after a specific character

Tags: regex

I'm using a software to edit songs using regular expressions. This is what I have:

> Jimmy Eat World - The Middle (.mp3)

What I would like to do is delete the space before the "-" and everything after, so I would just be left with "Jimmy Eat World"

And the other action that I would like to perform is to delete everything up to the "-" and the space following so I'd be left with just "The Middle"

Comment: Is the `(.mp3)` part of your actual input?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's an easy one.

**First action** - Remove anything after the dash:

- Replace `/ -.*/` with the empty string. (Note there's an actual space before the dash.)
- If there could be multiple spaces before the dash, you can use this variant: `/ +-.*/` (again with an actual space before the `+`).

**Second action** - Remove anything up to the dash:

- Replace `/.* - /` with the empty string. (Note there's an actual space after the dash.)

Notes

- The slashes `/` above are not part of the regex, you won't have to type them. They serve as a visual delimiter here.
- The `.` means *"any character"* (except newlines, which you won't have anyway in filenames)
- The `*` means *"the previous item, zero to any number of times"*
- The `+` means *"the previous item, at least once, possibly any number of times"*
- Most other characters in regular expressions mean what they say, so a space in the regex will match a space in your string. Notable exceptions are `^`, `$`, `.`, `+`, `*`, `?`, `{`, `}`, `(`, `)`, `[`, `]`, `|` and `\`, which have their own special meaning but are of no deeper concern in your situation.

Comment: `(``)` are of deeper concern here (especially when this comes to the update). Note that I suggest always escaping non-alphanumeric characters.

Comment: @Jan It is mandatory in my first expression, I've changed my second one. The parentheses are of no concern since they are - if at all - part of the *input*, not part of the expression. I wholeheartedly dis-recommend mindlessly escaping all kinds of things in regular expressions. Only the things that need escaping should be escaped. Everything else in the long run leads to a very cloudy view on how regexes really work.

Comment: The second part requires extracting "The Middle", so the parentheses _are_ of concern.

Comment: @Jan Ah, you're right. Misunderstanding of the requirements on my part.

Comment: I agree overescaping could reduce readability. However, sometimes I'm not sure which _are_ special and require escaping, and I don't want to research.

Comment: @Jan See, that's what I mean. :) It leads to escaping voodoo and a kind of *"bang on it until the stupid thing works"* attitude that makes so many developers so hopelessly bad at regex. Sharp tools require sharp knowledge - escaping everything just for good measure is the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

Is your program able to extract groups surrounded by parentheses in the regular expression? If so, you could create an expression like this one here (the example is written in Python):

```
In [1]: import re    

In [2]: match_obj = re.match(r'(.+?)\s*-\s*(.+?)\.mp3', 'Jimmy Eat World - The Middle.mp3')

In [3]: match_obj.group(1)
Out[3]: 'Jimmy Eat World'

In [4]: match_obj.group(2)
Out[4]: 'The Middle'
```

Answer (score 1):

This will match the first hyphen surrounded with whitespace, the whitespace, and everything after it (replace with the empty string):

```
\s\-\s.*
```

This will match the first hyphen surrounded with whitespace, the whitespace, and everything before it:

```
.*\s\-\s
```

This will match the literal `(.mp3)` and an optional whitespace (any amount) before it:

```
\s*\(\.mp3\)
```

Answer (score 0):

For retrieving the song name try replacing `.*-\s*` with nothing. Then replace `\s*\(\.mp3\)` with nothing.

In the event you have various filetypes such as MP3 and WMA you could add the additional file types to the second regex like so: `\s*\(\.(mp3|wma|avi|mpg|mpeg)\)`.