# Java - how can i remove a word after using a special symbol

Tags: java, stack

How can i delete a word which is followed by a special character ( # )? Ex: From a phrase: Eva have green#eyes I would like to delete the word "green" (Eva have eyes), that is the word that ends on a space.

Also I have problem with deleting the whole line that is followed by @,

ex: `Eva have green@eyes` ---> and should be "`eyes`"
my code (I have no idea haw can I complete it):

```
class Stack {

public Stack() {
    del = '&';    //that method deletes only one character
                  //ex: ab&cd ---> acd
    destroy = '@';
    delWord = '#';
    stack = new Stack<Character>();

}

public void methods(String string)
{

    for (int i=0; i< string.length(); i++) //that method deletes only one character
                                       //ex: ab&cd ---> acd
    {
       if ( del == string.charAt(i) )
       {
          if (stack.size() > 0)
             stack.remove(stack.size()-1);
       }
       else if( destroy == string.charAt(i) )
      {
       stack.remove(stack.size());

      }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184305/regex-deleting-words-after-a-specific-character

Comment: Read here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String) and learn about regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the replaceAll method in the String class, e.g.

```
String myString = "eyes#green"
myString = myString.replaceAll("#.*", " ");
```

The first argument is a regular expression matching what you want to replace. In this case hashtag followed by anything (i.e. matching the remainder of the string).

The second argument is what it should be replaced with, in this case a space.

Modify the regex as needed for your purposes.

Comment: thanks, but I can't replace them because they must work as they have some function to do, e.g. if I have a sequence of characters ab&&cd the first transformation should delete "b", the second should delete "a" so the result should be "cd". The same is with #: if I have a phrase Eva have green@@ eyes the first transformation shuould delete the word "green" and the second the word "have" so in the result I should obtain "Eva eyes"

Answer (score 0):

To delet the whole line that is followed by `@` , Try this:

```
String s = "Eva have green@eyes";
s = s.replaceAll(".*@"," ");
System.out.println(s);
```

**The Output :** `eyes`

---

and to remove word before `#` , Try this:

```
String s= "Eva have green#eyes ";
s= s.replaceAll("\\s*(\\w+)#", " ");
System.out.println(s);
```

**The Output :** `Eva have eyes`

Comment: and if i type another word?

Comment: Try it with another word , first one delete from beginning to `@` , and the second one just delete the word between space and `#`

Answer (score 0):

you can transform your string into array:

```
String[] string = plainText.split(" ,;[(!)*=]")//not using your #
```

then transform it to ArrayList, using simple `for(String word: arraylist)`
check every word for existance of # and if you find such word not to write it to the other ArrayList or right to the String array